# Save canvas image with background - Windows 8 c# metro app?

Tags: canvas, windows-8, background, microsoft-metro, save

I would like to save my canvas with its background image. But when i saved the all, there is only my lines and nothing else.

My classic code to "save the canvas" :

```
    private async void save_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_inkManager.GetStrokes().Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker save = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
                save.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
                save.DefaultFileExtension = ".png";
                save.FileTypeChoices.Add("PNG", new string[] { ".png" });
                StorageFile filesave = await save.PickSaveFileAsync();
                IOutputStream ab = await filesave.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                if (ab != null)
                    await _inkManager.SaveAsync(ab);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you have any idea how i can resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are saving your canvas - you are saving the [InkManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242141.aspx) (which in the docs say it saves only the strokes, nothing else).. Note that InkManager is not a UI element - it's simply an object that you "hook".

Canvas (and all other UIElements) cannot be transformed into an Image as far as I know. That's a limitation Win8 has that Silverlight/WPF does not which irks me the most.

Comment: Thanks, i saw this. I need to do a merge of my canvas background and the export of the strokes.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, the only way i found is to save those strokes and merge with another image.